# Docker - WordPress - Localhost ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, localhost

I started working with Docker for WordPress. I followed the docker documentation to get it up and running:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/

I added volumes for the plugin & theme directory.

When ran the command `docker-compose up -d` the first time and went to http://localhost:8000/ i saw the installation of WordPress. When i rebooted my PC and started the services again with: `docker-compose up -d` or `docker-compose start` i got the error message: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

I tried:

- Removing the containers, services and volumes
- Killing the netstat port

Currently I have no idea why it isn't working anymore. I am working on macOS

This is my current docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     volumes:
      - ./plugins/my-plugin:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin
      - ./themes/my-theme:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/my-theme
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpres
volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

The status of containers after running it:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you run `docker-compose down`? Run it twice, it will then remove the network as well. Once that is done. You can run `docker-compose up -d` - Make sure you are in the correct dir.

Comment: I did, i tried to run docker-compose up instead of docker-compose up -d and it says: MySQL Connection Error: (1045) Access denied for user 'wordpress'@'172.23.0.3' (using password: YES).

the docker-compose.yml is a copy from: https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/

Comment: Could you try these steps 
1. `docker-compose down` - twice
2. Edit the yml file and replace all instances of  `db_data` with `db_datax` 
3. Run `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: Now it works o.O. What is the difference between db_data and db_datax. Does is still persists the changes in the database?

Comment: This one would be a new instance - The mounted dir is different now. Hope this helps

Comment: After i am done working on it, what is the correct way of shutting down docker. So when i want to continue i can just do docker-compose up -d

Comment: `docker-compose down` - This should be enough.

Comment: Is is possible to change the YML so i can create a new DB and switch between them? or should i use env. file for it?

Comment: Sir I am not quite getting your use case here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186978/discussion-between-valerian-pereira-and-marc).

Comment: After i installed WordPress i can work with this container(project-1). The db_datax persists my changes. But if i need a new database for project-2. How can i create a new DB (project-2) and still have the option to switch back to the project-1 if needed.

Comment: You will have to connect to the MySQL service using a client - to create your database. You can then update the Wordpress config to point to the new database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps

1. `docker-compose down` - twice
2. Edit the yml file and replace all instances of db_data with db_datax
3. Run `docker-compose up -d`

Alternately,

1. `docker-compose down` - twice {removes the network as well}
2. `docker system prune --volumes`
3. `docker-compose up -d`